# How to make a parametric that matches a vector field?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vector-fields, mathematics

So I have a vector field defined as $(X(x,y),Y(x,y))$ and I’m trying to make a parametric $(t,t)$ who’s derivative at a point is equal to the vector field at that point.
for example the vector field $(y,-x)$ and the parametric $(sin(t),cos(t))$ would work, but how to I calculate this parametric from any starting point P and any vector field. The reason I’m doing this is to find out more about fluid flow in a vector field.

Comment: 'Streamlines' or 'pathlines' is the concept you want. These are 2 different things

Comment: What are streamlines and pathlines?

Comment: Streamlines are the curves a vector field makes when you take a "snapshot " of it. And is found by solving $$\vec{dr}×\vec{F}=0$$ Pathlines are the curves found by solving the equations of motion of a particle inside of the vector field. These two are equivalent if the vector field is time independent.  These concepts are one of the first ideas you learn when learning Fluid mechanics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a differential equation. Or rather, two differential equations. Or, more specifically, an initial value problem.

You want to find functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ that satisfy the first order differential equation initial value problem

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = X\left(x(t),y(t)\right)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = Y\left(x(t),y(t)\right)$$
$$ x(t=0) = x_0$$
$$ y(t=0) = y_0$$

where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are your starting coordinates.

Depending on the vector field this system of differential equations may be very easy or very hard to solve. My guess is the confusing part of setting up this process is understanding the difference between the functions $X(x,y)$ and $Y(x,y)$ and the solution functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

If you know what a differential equation is you just have to solve it. If you don't know what a differential equation or an initial value problem is then you have an exciting learning journey ahead of you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been trying at this for a while now and you explained it in a really nice way.

Comment: Wait but how do I put in the starting point

Comment: Added a bit about the initial values and the term "initial value problem"